# kubeflow pipeline ml_metadata mysql_real_connect failed

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow-pipelines

I am trying to build kubeflow pipeline

metadata-deployment

When Kubeflow connected data, the following questions occurred. What do I need to operate? I have now set up the database and the user password is confirmed to be correct

> **That's official ⬇️**

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  password: aG05WGJCb2s3ZEdUNDR0eQ==
  username: YWRtaW4=
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-credential
  namespace: kubeflow
type: Opaque

------------------
env:
- name: DBCONFIG_USER
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      key: username
      name: mysql-credential
- name: DBCONFIG_PASSWORD
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      key: password
      name: mysql-credential
```

And so is my configuration

> LOG ERROR

```
2020-09-27 10:16:51.065292: F ml_metadata/metadata_store/metadata_store_server_main.cc:178] Non-OK-status: ml_metadata::CreateMetadataStore(connection_config, &metadata_store) status: Internal: mysql_real_connect failed: errno: 1045, error: Access denied for user 'admin'@'10.22.0.185' (using password: YES)MetadataStore cannot be created with the given connection config.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to:

- Check for typo error: username or password.
- Check the host name and compare it with mysql.user table host name
- Check user exists or not.
- Check whether host contains IP address or host name.
- Check if mysql DB works.
  Run:  `mysql -D ${MYSQL_DATABASE} -u root -p${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD} -e 'SELECT 1'`  on  `mysql`  pod
- Check that PVC is properly bounded:  `kubectl get pvc mysql -n kubeflow`
- Check the volume are you using for the mysql PV -
  If it is local hostPath, try to delete directory on the k8s cluster node

See more: [mysql-errno-1045](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47279949/11300382).

Take a look: [access-denied-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw),  [kubeflow-mysql-pipeline](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/4610), [kubeflow-mysql](https://github.com/kubeflow/katib/issues/1212).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer
The database that my Kubeflow connects to is a remote database, and the account password is also set correctly. I can successfully connect through Python. I have a question, about yaml file, is this the only place to configure the connection of mysql (the figure illustrated in the question)

Comment: Please can you provide this specification and extra question into your post ? Also if your find workaround - connect to database please post it as an extra answer.